# How can a limit of an axis be required to be greater than or equal to 0 in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, limit, axes

I want to set a requirement that the minimum limit of the y-axis be greater than or equal to 0. I do *not* want to set the minimum limit of the y-axis to be exactly 0.

I do not want to set the y-axis minimum limit to 0 because the plot would be as follows:

[image]

I want to require the y-axis minimum limit to be greater than or equal to 0 while not setting it exactly to 0 so that the plot can look as follows:

[image]

So, what should I do instead of the following?

```
axes = matplotlib.pyplot.gca()
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.0f"))
axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.0f"))
axes.set_xlim(left = 0)
axes.set_ylim(bottom = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `get_xlim` and `get_ylim` to get the auto generated limits.  Then take the max of the lower bound and 0 and use that in `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`.

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you very much for the details on the `get_*lim` approach.